# Slow query - how to improve query performance in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 449383 records. When I execute below query it takes a lot of time to get 32643 records.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT  alloc_id,  cr_number,  profile_id,  table_id,  provider_id,
        user_id,  team_id,  trans_reason_id,  trans_reason,  data_id,
        trans_fr_provider_id,  trans_to_provider_id,  from_office_team_id,
        to_office_team_id,  trans_fr_resp_officer_id,
        trans_to_resp_officer_id,   fr_team,  to_team,  fr_officer,
        to_officer,  start_date,  end_date,  alloc_date,  request_type,
        tr_id,  desc_id,  desc,  bd_status_id,  active,   display_order,
        created_date,  created_by,  created_by_user_id,  modified_date,
        modified_by,  modified_by_user_id,  deleted,  deleted_date,
        deleted_by,   deleted_by_user_id,  locked,  version
FROM    cm_alloc_spg
WHERE   team_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND end_date IS NULL AND locked = 0 
LIMIT   1000000;
```

Execution plan:

```
 id  select_type  table         type  possible_keys            key     key_len  ref      rows  Extra   
---  -----------  ------------  ----  -------------            ------  -------  -----  ------  ----------------------------------
  1  SIMPLE       cm_alloc_spg  ref   team_idx,ed_idx,loc_idx  ed_idx       4   const  228838  Using index condition; Using where
```

Create Query Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `cm_alloc_spg` (
  `alloc_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cr_number` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `table_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `provider_id` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_reason_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_reason` VARCHAR(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `trans_fr_provider_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_to_provider_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_office_team_id` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_office_team_id` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_fr_resp_officer_id` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_to_resp_officer_id` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fr_team` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_team` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fr_officer` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_officer` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `end_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `alloc_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_type` VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tr_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_id` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` VARCHAR(700) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bd_status_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 0,
  `display_order` INT(4) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  `created_by` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_by_user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  `modified_by` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `modified_by_user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `deleted_date` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by_user_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `version` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`alloc_id`),
  KEY `fk_profile_id_idx` (`profile_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_id_idx` (`user_id`),
  KEY `team_idx` (`team_id`),
  KEY `cr_number_idx` (`cr_number`),
  KEY `tab_idx` (`table_id`),
  KEY `ed_idx` (`end_date`),
  KEY `loc_idx` (`locked`),
  KEY `alloc_date_idx` (`alloc_date`),
  KEY `tr_id_idx` (`tr_id`),
  KEY `del_idx` (`deleted`),
  KEY `to_off_team_id_idx` (`to_office_team_id`),
  KEY `trns_res_offcr_id_idx` (`trans_to_resp_officer_id`),
  KEY `active_idx` (`active`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

How can I improve the query's efficiency?

Comment: But what do you expect? Returning 32k of records will NOT BE fast.

Comment: "it takes a lot of time" - You should be more precise. You probably can't do anything. The used index seems to be optimal.

Comment: it will take near about 6-7 sec

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use paging, i suggest never get all data if you have large number of records.

> SELECT alloc_id, cr_number, profile_id, table_id, provider_id, user_id, team_id, trans_reason_id, trans_reason, data_id,
>   trans_fr_provider_id, trans_to_provider_id, from_office_team_id, to_office_team_id, trans_fr_resp_officer_id, trans_to_resp_officer_id, fr_team, to_team, fr_officer, to_officer, start_date, end_date, alloc_date, request_type, tr_id, desc_id, desc, bd_status_id, active, display_order, created_date, created_by, created_by_user_id, modified_date, modified_by, modified_by_user_id, deleted, deleted_date, deleted_by, deleted_by_user_id, locked, version FROM cm_alloc_spg WHERE team_id IS NOT NULL AND end_date IS NULL AND locked = 0 LIMIT 0,100;

limit clause syntax index,no of rows you want to retrive

Comment: i am getting only  32643 records after executing query. i want to see all record that's y i am using limit

Answer (score 0):

Gupta, you can do one thing just make team_id, end_data and locked **index** in this table.
You can easily make any attribute index by 
example

> CREATE  INDEX team_id_1 ON cm_alloc_spg(team_id);

It will improve your query speed more than 30 times.
Comment down for any help.

Comment: but you are doing where clause with end_date and locked, so they need to be indexed too.

Comment: Will not matter ideally the topicstarter @S.gupta should make a multi columns index  `(team_id, end_date, locked)`

Comment: I have create index on team_id,end_date and locked column

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes you are right, S.gupta please do it and check

Comment: @S.gupta please make group index on all three it will impact.

Comment: @Raymond, i have created multi column but not improvement on result

Comment: @S.gupta on which you are checking it phpmyadmin?

Comment: i am using sqlyog

Comment: " i have created multi column but not improvement on result" Well never mind mine comment @S.gupta i missed the fact the query returned 32643 records.. i need coffee..